# Can't resolve method of 'enter' in 'Context'

Tags: java, gradle

Actually I am trying to resolve those red line characters but I haven't find out any way to resolve. I have tried to import some js and rhino files but it's not working.

I have tried to import the :
`import org.mozilla.javascript.context` but this file is not importing to the ide.

I hope I will find a better solution.

[image]

Comment: Remove those `sourceName:` etc... you're not supposed to write the parameter name. So `evaluateString(scriptable, data, "javascript", 1, null).toString()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't 'do' named parameters. `someMethod(param1Name: param1Value)` just isn't java. You are seeing it, though - see that `regex:` thing in your `replaceAll` calls a few lines up? But that's not *code*. That is intellij annotating your source file for you. That `regex:` isn't in your source file (and if it was, it wouldn't compile - that isn't java), it's intellij rendering your source file in a fancy fashion, to make it easier to read.

Thus, remove `lineno:` and `securityDomain:`.

NB: It's clearly not working here. That `regex:` should have tipped you off. replaceAll is wrong here. You should use `replace`. `replace` **also** replaces all occurrences. `replaceAll` is regexp based, `replace` isn't. These aren't regexps.